# Crash when adding QGraphicsProxyWidget

Tags: qt, crash, scene

I'm trying to have a `QPushButton` in my scene, but when I'm trying to add the `QGraphicsProxyWidget` to the scene, it crashes.

So here's the `.cpp`:

```
#include "upgradecromagnon.h"
#include "game.h"
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <qDebug>

extern Game *game;
UpgradeCromagnon::UpgradeCromagnon()
{

    this->setRect(-50,0,150,50);
    buttonAmelio = new QPushButton("salut");
    teste();
}

void UpgradeCromagnon::teste()
{
    QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();
    proxy->setWidget(buttonAmelio);
    scene()->addItem(proxy);
}
```

and its `.h`:

```
#ifndef UPGRADECROMAGNON_H
#define UPGRADECROMAGNON_H
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QPushButton>
class UpgradeCromagnon: public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    UpgradeCromagnon();
    void teste();
private:
    QPushButton *buttonAmelio;
};

#endif // UPGRADECROMAGNON_H
```

Comment: Does `scene()` definitely return non-null when called in `UpgradeCromagnon::teste`?

Comment: Well i can had other classes before so the scene has been set at this point :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `UpgradeCromagnon` constructor calls `UpgradeCromagnon::teste` which, in turn, calls `QGraphicsItem::scene`.  At that point `QGraphicsItem::scene` *must* return a null pointer since there's no possible way the `UpgradeCromagnon` instance can have been added to a `QGraphicsScene` before its contructor has completed (not according to the code you've provided at any rate).